# Setting 'allowBackup=false' clear shared preferences on app update in Android devices

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I am trying to signout the users when they update the apps. For that setting allowBackup=false, will it clear the shared preferences when the app is updated?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This will help you with more details-https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup, Becasuse shared preferences and Allow Backup is different work in android.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences will not be cleared on an update. `allowBackup` will have no effect on that either as it is only used for new installations. You could use SharedPreferences to track the previous version and sign the user out if it no longer matches.

Example:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  val sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
  val previousVersion = sharedPref.getInt(VERSION_KEY, -1)
  val currentVersion = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
  if (previousVersion != currentVersion) {
    // The app has been updated, sign the user out.
    sharedPref.edit().putInt(VERSION_KEY, currentVersion).apply()
  }
}

companion object {
  private const val VERSION_KEY = "appVersion"
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more info on that? How do I make them signout on app update? right now that's what I have implemented, doesn't seem to work:
if (intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED) {
                val settings = context?.getSharedPreferences("<sharedpreference_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
         
                    if (context != null) {
                        context.startActivity(intent)
                    }
                    settings.edit().clear().apply()
                }
         
            }

Comment: I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. So my question is :onCreate fun is the first in view that open up on my app ? by signing out do you mean implementing this code:
 val settings = context?.getSharedPreferences("<sharedpreference_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) if (context != null) { context.startActivity(intent) } settings.edit().clear().apply() } 

sorry, just wanted to make sure i am doing it right this time.

Comment: You would put this in your launcher activity. The definition of signing out is dependent on your app's implementation so it goes beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Got it. Can I not just have check if(BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE != "current version of the app") {
//sign out the customer. not the best fix, but can i solve the problem for this release ??
}

Comment: BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE is the current version of the app. You need to persist the previously installed version's VERSION_CODE so that it can be compared after a new update.

Comment: There is also a default value so the next update will also sign out the user.

Comment: But just for this fix, if I know the new app version, can i simply not use the code in mentioned  in my last comment and sign them out. In future releases I can always update the version value in if check? I know that;s not the best solution, but will it work for me this time ?

Comment: I don't understand why you need a compromise for this version. The code I provided will work in all cases.

Comment: Feel free to copy my code, but I'd recommend understanding it if you are going to be putting it into your app. VERSION_KEY is not required, but it's best practice to pull static constant values into a companion object rather than in code.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

No, `allowBackup=false` disables backup only for installation, not for update.
In your case you should save a last version of your app in SharedPrefs and compare with current (on runtime) and decide to clear data or not.

Comment: Can you please provide more info on that? How do I make them signout on app update? right now that's what I have implemented, doesn't seem to work: if (intent?.action == Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED) { val settings = context?.getSharedPreferences("<sharedpreference_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE) if (context != null) { context.startActivity(intent) } settings.edit().clear().apply() } }

Comment: ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED is BroadcastReceiver action code, so to implement this you should create BroadcastReceiver app component. I think the easiest way is to save last version in SharedPrefs

Comment: I have already implemented BroadcastReceiver,
can I use the following in the function:
String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    runtime.exec("pm clear "+packageName);

Comment: Yes, you can handle it in onReceive method

Comment: great. it worked. really appreciate it.

Comment: please leave a like on answer)